# QT Text.WordWrap not working inside ColumnLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am developing application using QT QML. I am facing one strange issue with QML. I want to divide and display long text using QML. I am using [QT Text](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html) element to perform this task. I want to place this Text inside [QT Columnlayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html) with other UI elements. I am not able to display long text as Multi line text. Please help me to solve this problem. Here is my QML code.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")
color: "#18d28a"

    ColumnLayout{
        id: base_coloumn_layout
        width: parent.width
        Layout.margins: 10

        Text {
            id: application_instruction
            width: 640
            text: qsTr("xyxvx dgdgdh dhdgdd dhdgdhhgd dhhhdgd dhdgdg dhdgdh djhddh djddgdhgdh dhdgdhgdgh dhgdgdhj dhdgdghdg dhjdgdgd.")
            color: "#000000"
            font.pointSize: 12
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        }
    }
}
```

Same element is working properly when placed outside `ColoumnLayout`. I am able to display Text as multi line with code bellow. I want same code should work as Child of `ColoumnLayout`as there will be few more elements inside `ColoumnLayout`

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")
color: "#18d28a"

    Text {
        id: application_instruction
        width: 640
        text: qsTr("xyxvx dgdgdh dhdgdd dhdgdhhgd dhhhdgd dhdgdg dhdgdh djhddh djddgdhgdh dhdgdhgdgh dhgdgdhj dhdgdghdg dhjdgdgd.")
        color: "#000000"
        font.pointSize: 12
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    }
}
```

What is wrong with ColoumnLayout. Am i missing any property value to set. Please help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inside a ColumnLayout, width properties are ignored.

Instead set `Layout.preferredWidth` or `Layout.maximumWidth` attached properties of the Text element.

If you want an item to fill the width of the ColumnLayout, you can set the `Layout.fillWidth` attached property to `true`.

Comment: Thanks very much Mark ch, after doing above change i am getting desired out put.

Comment: I just read your answer... There is another, possibly more appropriate way, I will add it....

Answer (score 0):

From the Answer given by Mark, we can change qml as given bellow and we can display multi line text.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: application_window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    color: "#18d28a"
    ColumnLayout {
        id: base_coloumn_layout
        width: parent.width
        Layout.margins: 10
        Text {
            id: application_instruction
            width: application_window.width
            Layout.preferredWidth: application_window.width
            text: qsTr("xyxvx dgdgdh dhdgdd dhdgdhhgd dhhhdgd dhdgdg dhdgdh djhddh djddgdhgdh dhdgdhgdgh dhgdgdhj dhdgdghdg dhjdgdgd.")
            color: "#000000"
            font.pointSize: 12
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        }
    }
}
```